# There exist a point $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that $p(x_0) = g(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial function in one variable of odd degree and $g(x)$ be a continuous function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$
Then which of the following statements are true.

1. There exist a point $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that $p(x_0) = g(x_0)$
2. If g is a polynomial function then there exist a point $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that $p(x_0) = g(x_0)$
3. If g is a bounded function then there exist a point $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that $p(x_0) = g(x_0)$
4. There is unique point $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that $p(x_0) = g(x_0)$

My Attempt:

When I take $p(x) = g(x) =x$ then options 1,2 are true and option 4 discarded. When I take $p(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1$ then option 3 is also true. We know that "there exist" means possibility to occurrence. So for there exist, particular example works good.
But In fact, correct option is 3 only. Please point out my mistake.

Comment: For (2) what if $p(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x + 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities 1. and 2. are false, because you can just take $g(x)=p(x)+1$, and then you never have $g(x_0)=p(x_0)$. And possibility 4. is false because if you take $g(x)=p(x)$ then, for every $x_0\in\Bbb R$, $g(x_0)=p(x_0)$.

On the other hand, if $g$ is bounded and if the leading coefficient of $p(x)$ is greater than $0$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)-g(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)-g(x)=-\infty$ and therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, $p(x_0)-g(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0$. And if the leading coefficient of $p(x)$ is smaller than $0$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)-g(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)-g(x)=\infty$; so, the same argument applies.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answer, 1, 2 and 4 are false. To prove that 3 is true, let $p$ be a polynomial off odd degree and assume, w.l.o.g., that the leading coefficient of $p$ is positive (otherwise replace $p$ and $g$ by $-p$ and $-g$). Then, if $g$ is continuous and bounded, $p - g$ is a continuous function such that $(p-g)(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$ and $(p-g)(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$. So we can choose $t > 0$ such that $(p-g)(-t) < 0$ and $(p-g)(t) > 0$. By the intermediate value theorem, $(p - g)(x) = 0$ for some $x_0 \in (-t, t)$, i.e., $p(x_0) = g(x_0)$